# Type hint when awaiting a Task

Tags: python, python-asyncio

Consider these two functions:

```py
@asyncio.coroutine
async def get_int() -> int:
    await asyncio.sleep(0.5)
    return 5


@asyncio.coroutine
async def get_str() -> str:
    await asyncio.sleep(0.5)
    return "str"
```

I would like to be get the first finished coroutine and its result, so I'm doing a `FIRST_COMPLETED` await:

```py
    next_int_coro = asyncio.Task(get_int())
    next_str_coro = asyncio.Task(get_str())

    done, pending = await asyncio.wait([next_int_coro, next_str_coro],
                                       return_when=asyncio.FIRST_COMPLETED)

    if next_int_coro in done:
        some_int = await next_int_coro # type hint for some_int = Any :(
        print(f"int : {some_int}")

    elif next_str_coro in done:
        some_str = await next_str_coro # type hint for some_str = Any :(
        print(f"str : {some_str}")
    else:
        print("unexpected coroutine ended")
```

The problem is that I would like to have type hints when handling the result of the tasks. Instead, I get `Any`.

Instead of wrapping the coroutine in a `Task`, I get the type hint all right if it's awaited directly:

```py
next_int_coro = get_int()
some_int = await next_int_coro # some_int is hinted to be an int
```

But in that case, I can't determine which coroutine ended first (the `if elif else` that checks whether a coroutine belongs to the "`done`" `Future` set ends up in the `else`).

How can I get the best of both worlds? I mean getting the type hints of the awaited result *and* being able to know which coroutine ended first.

Comment: What about using something like `Callable[[int], Awaitable[None]]` ?

Comment: could you expand?

Comment: There isn't a great way for a static analyzer to know which coroutine will perform faster at runtime. Your best options are probably ducktyping, `isinstance`, and returning a container that exposes each type as a separate attribute and using something like `if result.integer_field is not None`. Unrelated: `asyncio.coroutine` and `async def` are redundant. The latter was introduced as the syntax to replace the former; you can remove the decoration.